# How to save a ConfigurationSection in a config file without specifying the version?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration-files

I'm using a custom ConfigurationSection that I'm saving into a file:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
configuration.Sections.Add("my-section-name, myCustomSection);
configuration.Save();
```

It does produce me the following config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="my-section-name" type="my.custom.section, AssemblyContainingCustomSection, Version=1.2.0.16289, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2db2a2387bac0a0a" />
  </configSections>
  <myCustomSection something="ABC">
    <subCollection>
      <subItem prop="833bcc9d-7e42-4ecd-b824-e5245d2e6a62" name="AAA" serverName="BBBB" file="C:\a\b\c\d.com" type="live" />
    </subCollection>
  </myCustomSection>
</configuration>
```

But the issue is with the "version" specified: I would like to avoid having it specified(or ignore it while opening it), because today if I open it with a different build, I get a  `Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyContainingCustomSection, Version=1.2.0.16289, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2db2a2387bac0a0a`

It's also perfectly fine if I can just say when I'm opening the config file that I don't care about the version.

It was working fine(without the version) up until I upgrade my solution from .Net 4.8 to .Net 7.

Thank you for your help